# Execute HtmlOutput code in Google App Script without opening a sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

edit: wound up using [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) to manipulate the elements instead of creating them in a sidebar.

Is it possible to create an execute `htmlOutput` in a background page, or do so without showing the user anything?

Sample code below:

plugin.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Start', 'run')
        .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 */
function run() {
    var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar').evaluate()
        .setTitle(constants.title);

    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

sidebar.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  console.log("Hello world!");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

This works, but it pops open the sidebar. If I comment out `DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);`, then the page is never created or executed.

Context: I'd like to run some scripts that need to use basic APIs/DOM manipulation like `window`, `document`, etc. These don't run on serverside `gs` files. I want this to happen without having to open a sidebar.

Comment: Do  a Logger.log( ui).

Comment: You can use the service to load data in to the html ouput and then use it in an email for htmlBody without ever having run an html page.

Comment: Take a look at [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what actions you want to accomplish with `window`, `document`, etc.? I don't understand why do you want this to execute if you don't want any HTML output to show up.

Comment: @lamblichus OP wants to run these to get something in the html.`document.getElementById(...).value`. Basically, He's looking for a html parser but with script capabilities-like [tag:puppeteer] or [tag:selenium]

Comment: I think a better way to go about this is to use a vitual dom like https://cheerio.js.org/. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Chanok Consider adding a answer